# Synapse Spark Pool Error HTTP Request failed to Authenticate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

It was running fine and suddenly getting below error

```
Error code 1

LIVY_JOB_STATE_DEAD

Message

[plugins.synapse-ent-tekura.sparkpoolsmall.180 WorkspaceType:<Synapse> CCID:<b6f6c9c4-250d-44c3-9c28-bce4525c42df>] 
[Monitoring] Livy Endpoint=[https://<url>:8001/api/v1.0/publish/1567bc8e-206c-475f-bf1f-7c550c17a6d6]. 
Livy Id=[23] Job failed during run time with state=[dead].
```

Source

Unknown

Spark logs is here :

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException: HTTP Error -1CustomTokenProvider getAccessToken threw java.io.IOException : POST failed with 'Unauthorized' (401) and message: {"result":"UserError","errorId":"Unauthorized","errorMessage":"Invalid JobSessionToken : IDX10249: X509SecurityKey validation failed. The associated certificate has expired. ValidTo (UTC): '1/28/2023 7:18:14 AM', Current time (UTC): '1/30/2023 7:06:05 PM'.. TraceId : f51d91bd-f786-4225-a223-e9401cf58527. Error Component : TokenService"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.CustomTokenProviderAdapter.refreshToken(CustomTokenProviderAdapter.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AccessTokenProvider.getToken(AccessTokenProvider.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAccessToken(AbfsClient.java:1055)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.executeHttpOperation(AbfsRestOperation.java:256)
    ... 26 more
23/01/30 19:06:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/01/30 19:06:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-16f17c6d-3914-46f6-979c-9da7c8149d86
23/01/30 19:06:05 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping azure-file-system metrics system...
23/01/30 19:06:05 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: azure-file-system metrics system stopped.
23/01/30 19:06:05 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: azure-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.
```

Failed to find which authentication is failed

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because of expired SSL certificate.

```
ValidTo (UTC): '1/28/2023 7:18:14 AM', 
Current time (UTC): '1/30/2023 7:06:05 PM'
```

If this is something managed by you then ask your infra team to renew the SSL certificates or wait for new certificate to be added if you do not know who manages these certificates.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I checked with infra team , they said they have no idea which certificate has expired. There is no custom SSL certificate has installed by infra team.Is there a way on how to find which certificate has expired?

Comment: It is very difficult to say anything just by looking at error. One endpoint I see here is Livy Endpoint=[https://<url>:8001